# Swift tuple to Optional assignment

Tags: ios, swift, tuples, option-type

I am writing some code in Swift to learn the language.  Here is my base class:

```
import Foundation
class BaseCommand:NSOperation
{
    var status:Int? = nil
    var message:String? = nil

    func buildRequest() -> NSData?
    {
        return nil
    }

    func parseResponse(data:NSData?) -> (Status:Int, Error:String)
    {
        return (200, "Success")
    }

    override func main() {
        let requestBody = self.buildRequest()

        println("Sending body \(requestBody)")
        // do network op
        var networkResultBody = "test"

        var resultBody:NSData = networkResultBody.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        (self.status, self.message) = self.parseResponse(resultBody)
    }
}
```

The problem is on the last line:

```
(self.status, self.message) = self.parseResponse(resultBody)
```

The compiler says "Cannot express tuple conversion (Status:Int, Error:String) to (Int?, String?)"

I understand that the issue is that self.status and self.message are optionals, and the parseResponse does not return Optionals (and I don't want it to).  How do I tell it to do the necessary assign and convert to get the data into the instance variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another answer suggested (before it was changed) to just do:

```
(self.status!, self.message!) = self.parseResponse(resultBody)
```

I have found that is unsafe.  It will crash if either `self.status` or `self.message` is `nil` at the time of the assignment.  Try this test in a Playground:

```
class Test {
    var status: Int?
    var error: String?

    func parseResponse() -> (Status:Int, Error:String)
    {
        return (200, "Success")
    }

    func testIt() {
        (self.status!, self.error!) = parseResponse()
        print(self.status)
        print(self.error)
    }
}

let mytest = Test()
mytest.testIt()
```

---

Here is another way it could be done:

```
let (stat, err) = self.parseResponse(resultBody)
(self.status, self.error) = (Optional(stat), Optional(err))
```

or, as @AndriyGordiychuk discovered, it works without `Optional`:

```
let (stat, err) = self.parseResponse(resultBody)
(self.status, self.error) = (stat, err)
```

It's curious that that works, but assigning the result of the function does not.

---

Note the following experiment:

```
var i: Int?
var s: String?

// This works
(i, s) = (3, "hello")

// This fails with error: cannot express tuple conversion '(Int, String)' to '(Int?, String?)
let t = (3, "hello")
(i, s) = t
```

It seems that when the assignment is a tuple literal assigned to a tuple, Swift takes a shortcut and doesn't first construct the tuple.  Instead, is just assigns the individual elements.

So this:

```
(i, s) = (3, "hello")
```

is equivalent to:

```
i = 3
s = "hello"
```

which works because you can assign an `Int` to an `Int?` variable and a `String` to a `String?` variable.  The tuple assignment fails because the types need to match.

Comment: you can decompose tuple and rebuild it 

     (i, s) = (t.0, t.1)

Answer (score 3):

You have to do this (no optionals needed):

```
let returnValue = self.parseResponse(resultBody)
(self.status,self.message) = (returnValue.Status,returnValue.Error)
```

Comment: Your first method will crash if `self.status` or `self.message` are `nil` at the time.

Comment: I have tested it. And it doesn't crash. Why would it? It would crash if you were unwrapping them and assigning to something that expects non-nil values. Explicitly unwrapping nil does not cause a crash by itself ;)

Comment: See my answer.  My playground test crashes in both Xcode 6.4 and 7.0 beta 5 if `self.status` or `self.message` are `nil`.

Comment: @vacawama ok, you are right. I have confused the print of the function output with the sign that all is working. Still, there is a better alternative to what you have suggested as Optional() can be omitted ;)

Comment: Up voting your latest answer.