# Understanding why this Swift tuple assignment isn't allowed

Tags: swift, tuples, swift3

The following code is fine:

```
func intTest() -> Int? {
    var res : Int

    res = 5

    return res
}
```

There is no problem returning a non-optional `Int` from a method with a return type of optional `Int`.

Now lets see what happens when the return value is a tuple of optional values:

```
func tupleTest() -> (Int?, Int?) {
    var res : (Int, Int)

    res = (5, 5)

    return res
}
```

The `return res` line results in the error:

> error: cannot express tuple conversion '(Int, Int)' to '(Int?, Int?)' (aka '(Optional, Optional)')

Why does Swift not allow this?

I certainly understand why this would be an error in the other direction (optional to non-optional) but why can't a tuple accept a non-optional value in the place of an optional when a non-tuple works fine?

I've seen [Swift tuple to Optional assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173623/swift-tuple-to-optional-assignment) but that doesn't cover why you can't do the assignment, it just covers how to solve it.

Comment: This seems like a good feature to have. I don't see why promotion to `Optional` would be disallowed for tuple members.

Answer (score 7):

The reason that's happening is because of a type mismatch. Consider the following case:

```
let myClosure: (Int) -> ()
let myOtherClosure: (Int?) -> ()
```

The type of `myClosure` is `(Int) -> ()` while `myOtherClosure` is of type `(Int?) -> ()` which makes them fundamentally different types, despite the similarity of the parameters. When Swift is looking at these two constants, it's evaluating the type as a whole, not the individual pieces. The same is happening with your tuple; it's looking at the tuple type signature as a whole unit, not breaking down the parameters and recognizing that they're non-optional versions of the same type.

Converting from `Int` to `Int?` works because they're the same type, one is just an optional. Going from `(Int, Int)` to `(Int?, Int?)` doesn't because the parameters of the tuple are different therefore causing the overall type to be different, hence your error.

Taking a look at one of your examples:

```
 func tupleTest() -> (Int?, Int?) {
    let first: Int = 1
    let second: Int = 2
    let res: (Int?, Int?) = (first, second)
    return res
 }
```

This works because even though the values are non-optional integers, the tuple type is marked as `(Int?, Int?)` whereas:

```
func tupleTest() -> (Int?, Int?) {
    let first: Int = 1
    let second: Int = 2
    let res = (first, second)
    return res
}
```

doesn't compile because now `res` is of type `(Int, Int)`. I'm not an expert on the Swift compiler but my guess is that the way the type system works is it doesn't deconstruct each individual part of a function or a tuple and recognize that the corresponding return parameter is the same type, just an optional.

Comment: Thanks for the details. But in a test I ran, I get the opposite results that I expected using your `myClosure` and `myOtherClosure` variables. If you change them to `var` and alternate assigning one variable to other, strangely you can assign the `(Int?) -> ()` closure to the `(Int) -> ()` variable but not the other way around. This is opposite of what I would expect and further confuses my original question.

Comment: @rmaddy That makes perfect sense, and is an example of function inputs being contravariant. You can assign a `(Int?) -> ()` to a `(Int) -> ()`, because any `Int` input passed in can be freely promoted to `Int?`, thus satisfying the assigned function's signature. If you consider being able to assign a `(Int) -> ()` to a `(Int?) -> ()`, then you could pass an optional input to a function that has a non-optional parameter, thus the assignment is illegal.

Comment: @Hamish OK, after some more experimenting I now see my confusion and understand why you can assign a `(Int?) -> ()` to a `(Int) -> ()` and not the other way around.

Comment: OK, now that I've cleared up that issue I'm my mind, this answer still confuses me. The argument is that you can't assign `(Int, Int)` to `(Int?, Int?)` because they are different types. But then why can you assign `(Int?) -> ()` to a `(Int) -> ()`? They are also different types but it works.

Comment: This just sounds like they couldn't be bothered to implement it as a programmer expects. Yet another example of swift being developed as a "prefect language" rather than something that is easy (and still safe) to to build apps in